# Whether the star schema needs to be created prior to creating the SSAS model?

Tags: ssas

I'm new to SSAS. While looking at examples I am seeing that reports query the SSAS model which is a star schema.

My question is - Given an OLTP database, is it possible to make a star schema directly in SSAS?

Or should I use an ETL to create the star schema into a data warehouse database and then use this data warehouse database's star schema to feed the SSAS?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you *couldn't* make an SSAS model that connects to the transactional database, it's more of a question of if you *should*.

If you don't have a lot of data, you're probably fine to just put the model to import mode and run the refresh at a time when not much is going on (also consider using some form of incremental refresh if you can). Just make some views that only bring in the columns you actually want and pull those views into the SSAS model.

Side note For compressions sake, order the views by columns that don't change very often and try not to bring in unnecessary primary keys.